# Does .NET 4 have a built-in JSON serializer/deserializer?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, jsonserializer

Does .NET 4 come with any class that serializes/deserializes JSON data?

- I know there are 3rd-party libraries, such as [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), but I am looking for something built right into .NET.
- I found [Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) on MSDN, but it is for WCF, not for Winforms or WPF.

Comment: JSON.Net is well supported and it appears that Microsoft intend to adopt it themselves *"We on the web team will be including JSON.NET as the default JSON Serializer in Web API when it releases, so that'll be nice."* from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: Just be aware of the embedded library for JSon serializing's **performance** in .Net!

Comment: @Babak what do you mean beware? Please elaborate.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono, It has not a very good performance. I'm using SimpleJSON not very easy to use but it has much better performance.

Comment: FWIW: I haven't tried SimpleJSON, but Newtonsoft's library (= JSON.NET) is easy to use, fairly well documented and - as far as I have experienced, and I use it extensively for de/serializing - very performant!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class anywhere you want, it is just a .net class and is not limited to WCF.  More info on how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,MSDN said DataContractJsonSerializer class in  Assembly:   System.Runtime.Serialization (in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll). However, VS2010 show error, cannot find DataContractJsonSerializer .

Comment: @TatMing
That's because, IIRC, pre .Net V4 it resides in System.ServiceModel.Web

Comment: Find that~ It about Target Framework problem, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825417/where-is-system-servicemodel-web-dll

Comment: The only problem with this is that you have to decorate your classes with attributes.

Answer (score 31):

There's the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class (although you will need to reference the  `System.Web.Extensions` assembly the class works perfectly fine in WinForms/WPF applications). Also even if the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class was designed for WCF it works fine in client applications.

Comment: FYI: Comparison between JsonSerializer and JavaScriptSerializer can be found [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301878/whats-the-difference-between-datacontractjsonserializer-and-javascriptserialize](here).

Comment: Also, JavaScriptSerializer is buried in the namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer for those looking for it.

Answer (score 12):

Use this generic class in order to serialize / deserialize JSON.
You can easy serialize complex data structure like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int[], bool, string>>
```

to JSON string and then to save it in application setting or else

```
public class JsonSerializer
{
    public string Serialize<T>(T Obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serialiser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            serialiser.WriteObject(ms, Obj);
            byte[] json = ms.ToArray();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string Json)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serialiser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var deserializedObj = (T)serialiser.ReadObject(ms);
            return deserializedObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `WriteObject` throws an error - there's a memory leak in this code. Better to wrap MemoryStream in a using statement eg `using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) { // code in here }`

Comment: WARNING!! Replace this line ser.WriteObject(ms, serializedObj); with this ser.WriteObject(ms, aObject);

Comment: Small bug on the Deserialize method.
Replace for:
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

Answer (score 0):

.NET4 has a built-in JSON Class,such as DataContractJsonSerializer ,but it is very weak,it doesn't support multidimentional array. I suggest you use JSON.Net