# How to create a json array in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable, ashx

How can i create a json array like this in ashx handler:

```
{ 
    "sEcho": 1, 
    "iTotalRecords": "57", 
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57", 
    "aaData": 
    [
         [ "Gecko", "Firefox 1.0", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", "1.7", "A" ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: See generated class(es) at http://json2csharp.com/ (the array part is a `List<List<string>>`, or similar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build it as anonymous object in dotnet and then serialize it as Json, Asp.Net has the serializer built in.

```
string json = context.Response.Write(Json(new { 
    sEcho = 1, 
    iTotalRecords = "57", 
    iTotalDisplayRecords = "57", 
    aaData = new List<List<String>>
    { new List<String>{ "Gecko", "Firefox 1.0", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", "1.7", "A" }}
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
```

**Update:**

Modified based on comments.

Comment: This is a `List<List`, not a `List<`

Comment: i must use c# library only

Comment: you may want to check this post to.  There are two options mentioned for built in json serializtion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275863/does-net-4-have-a-built-in-json-serializer-deserializer