# Create array from nested lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

A little difficult to explain, but here goes... (using .net 4.5, C#)

We currently have a list of items ( as per below "User") which contains a list of column objects. ie.

```
 public class TableColumn
{
    public string ColumnHeader { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }  
}

public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<TableColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

We are working with JQGrid where we are required to pass back Json.

without the nested list we would use :-

```
var aaData = PatList.Select(d => new string[] { 
              d.Username ,
              d.Address1 ,
              d.Age}).ToArray();

 return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            aaData = aaData,
            iTotalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(totalRowsCount.Value),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = Convert.ToInt32(filteredRowsCount.Value)
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

which works great.

What we are struggling with is how to add in the list of columns.

```
   var aaData = PatList.Select(d => new string[] { 
              d.Username ,
              d.Address1 ,
              d.Age,
              d.Columns.forEach(????)}).ToArray();
```

so the columns are related to a user.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need your data output in JSON format (i.e. your list of Users and their associated object graphs) you might want to consider using a JSON serializer. Have a look at [Does .NET 4 have a built-in JSON serializer/deserializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275863/does-net-4-have-a-built-in-json-serializer-deserializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var aaData = PatList.Select(d => (new string[] { 
        d.Username,
        d.Address1,
        d.Age.ToString()
    }.Union(d.Columns.Select(c => c.ColumnHeader))).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

This generates for every `User` in `PatList` an array with `Username, Address1, Age & all ColumnHeaders`.

Comment: thank you This worked, however, it removed many empty columns, which if im representing within a table, id still need. Managed to get around this by using concat rather than union                                                              var aaData = PatList.Select(d => (new string[] { 
        d.Username,
        d.Address1,
        d.Age.ToString()
    }.Concat(d.Columns.Select(c => c.ColumnHeader))).ToArray()
).ToArray();

Comment: Yes, `Union` removes duplicate / empty headers.