# Is this a correct JSON? How we can parse it?

Tags: json, wcf

My web service is returning below mentioned output as JSON,

```
{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 01, 2013","Performance":106917}]}
```

But I doubt cause I am not able to parse it.
If it is correct pls tell me how to parse it? I want to bind it to chart.

Full code

```
var retVal = '{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 01, 2013","Performance":106917},{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 02, 2013","Performance":119542}]}';
alert('Before parsing ' + retVal);
var passValue = JSON.parse(retVal);
alert('After parsing Count ' + passValue.count);
```

last alert give output as After parsing Count undefined.

Comment: Your json is fine @AK47. If you want to check, you can check your json at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/  or jsonlint.com

Comment: Guys I want to parse in javascript , can u help me with code? assign this json string to varable ...

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: yes tried that but it shows as undefined. pls check my question again I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to parse your json in javascript is that you store it inside a variable and can proceed like this:

```
var jsonString=JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

then you can fetch each key and their value accordingly.

Just check your json on JsonEditoronline.org for a better way of reading this.

This is sample of how I read my json in javascript:

```
success:function(responseText)
                {
                     alert(responseText);
                    return false; 

                    var object= JSON.parse(responseText);
                    var response= object.response;
                    var div=$('<div></div>');
                    var docs= response.docs;
```

where my json was something like this:

```
{"response":{"docs":""}}
```

Hope it helps.

I parsed your json using javascript and was able  to parse it using :

```
var myString='{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 01, 2013","Performance":106917}]}';

               var jsonString=JSON.parse(myString);
               alert("---------==="+jsonString);

               var fetch= jsonString.FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult;
               alert("llllllll    -- "+fetch.length);

               var time= fetch[0].DailyTimeStamp;
               alert(time);
```

Comment: OMG! Got it it took 2 complete days to understand me that there will be hierarchy in result object I was trying to skip "FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult". Anyway thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Pleasure buddy. Thats why I asked you to check your json at jsoneditoronline because it displays your json in hierarchical format and gives you a better understanding of it. Happy coding..  :)

Comment: still after looking at JsonEditoronline.org I was not able to understand it. But after you shared code in detail (var fetch..) I understood the issue. Thanks again friend.

Answer (score 2):

To tell if JSON is correct, you can use http://jsonlint.com/ Your JSON is correct. To parse it, use the .net JSON Deserializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx or JSON.NET Also see here for some discussion: [Does .NET 4 have a built-in JSON serializer/deserializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275863/does-net-4-have-a-built-in-json-serializer-deserializer)

EDIT: as you want Javascript, use JSON.parse. See some discussion here: http://www.json.org/js.html which also explains why you should not use eval(json), which does also work, but is considered a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your json output is correct and you can check yourself here is the [Link](http://json2csharp.com/), this will help you convert your json to c# class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That is a valid JSON String. You can check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is legal - php `json_decode('{"FetchSitePerformanceAutoResult":[{"DailyTimeStamp":"Nov 01, 2013","Performance":106917}]}');` parses it fine.