# How to use dropbox shares api

Tags: c#, dropbox

I'm a beginner in c# and for some time i'm trying to figure out how to get the  share link from a file I uploaded on dropbox.I'd be very grateful if you help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Shares API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares).

You need to make a web request to

https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/auto/`<path>`

where `<path>` is the file or folder you want to link to.

That call will return a JSON object, which is a string formatted in a particular way to represent serialized object data.

Have a look at [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the request.  There are several options available to [convert the JSON response into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3275863/141172) (that is, to deserialize it).

Try to write some code using this guidance.  If you get stuck, post a new question, include your code, and explain where you are stuck.