# retrieving JSON data from ASMX Web Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8, webservice-client

I'm trying to connect to a VB.net web service (ASMX) written in visual studio 2013 from a new Windows 8 Phone app VB.net written in visual studio 2015 community edition passing data between the two via JSON.

I think the web service is working okay and I get the following response when running it in the browser and clicking invoke:-

```
<string xmlns="http://SERVERNAME/">
[{"picksheet":"37760","seq":"24"},{"picksheet":"63245","seq":"20"},{"picksheet":"63818","seq":"23"},{"picksheet":"72162","seq":"16"}]
</string>
```

I seem to be able to get the actual JSON response back in the windows phone 8 app via the following code:-

```
Dim httpClient As HttpClient = New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.[Get], "http://WebServiceIPAddress/WebServices.asmx/GetPicksheetsAsJSON")
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.SendAsync(request)
If response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    Dim json As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result.ToString
    'POPULATE THE CLASS HERE
End If
```

My intention is to populate a class of picksheets from the above data, then iterate through them as necessary:-

```
Public Class clsPicksheets
    Private _Picksheet As String
    Private _Seq As String

    Public Property Picksheet() As String
        Get
            Return _Picksheet
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Picksheet = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Seq() As String
        Get
            Return _Seq
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Seq = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Getting the JSON data into the picksheets class is where I'm having trouble, I've tried numerous methods after googling the issue, but still no joy after 2 days.

An example of the above working with a means to iterate through each picksheet is what I'm after ultimately.

Forgive me if the following is a simple fix, but I've not had any experience with Web Services, C# (which seems to be what all the examples I've found are written in), Windows Phone 8 development or JSON data.  :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated to this first post to SO.

Many Thanks for any responses.

Comment: The deserialize functionality of the json.net library should sort you out. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. If you're looking for a built in json deserializer see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275863/does-net-4-have-a-built-in-json-serializer-deserializer

Comment: Thanks @FloatingKiwi I have aread online that the performance of the built in deserializer isn't very good and may not be compatible with windows phone 8?