# System.ServiceModel.dll missing in references visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I want to use `ChannelFactory<TChannel> Class` I am trying to add reference to `System.ServiceModel.dll` but I not see it in the references .

I see there `System.ServiceModel.web.dll` but it is something different .

I am using VS 2010 .net 3.5.

Any idea what is the issue here ?

Comment: Are you sure the project is not set to "3.5 client profile"?

Comment: @Johann Blais , I am using regular 3.5

Comment: according to msdn it's also supported in 3.5 client profile with sp1. I don't know though, I can't access my pc. But you may try to check updates for sp1 if you did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right click on the project in solution explorer, properties, then check again and select .NET Framework 3.5 and not client profile, all other info you might need are here, including a helpful screenshot: [Where is System.ServiceModel.Web.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825417/where-is-system-servicemodel-web-dll)

Answer (score 13):

Do:

1. Add reference.
2. Browse, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll
3. Click OK

That worked for me

Comment: I take it that I need to target a higher framework than v3.0 when the missing reference is:  `System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things, but in my case I had to downgrade the version Im using. Note that System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.10.2 is compatible with .NET 6.0, .NET Standard 1.0, .NET Framework 4.5. That will let you use it on .net Framework and .net core apps.
Please refer to this web for more information:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Primitives/4.10.2